# Loading HTML into "floating" DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery and one of the things I am trying to accomplish is to load some information about a selected record into a "floating div". For example I might have a list of records that as I mouseover each one a floating DIV element would appear with related information.

I know how to load the information into a DIV element contained within the page but I am unsure of how to have the DIV appear next to the link that I "hover" over. Does jQuery have a special function to allow for this?

Perhaps an example would help explain ...

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showRecordInfo(selectedRecordID) {                       
      $("#divDisplayInfo").load("GetRecordInfo.aspx",
                         { recordID: selectedRecordID }); 
    }
  </script>
  <body>
   <a href="#" onmouseover="showRecordInfo(1);">Record 1</a>
   <a href="#" onmouseover="showRecordInfo(2);">Record 2</a>
   <a href="#" onmouseover="showRecordInfo(3);">Record 3</a>

   <div id="divDisplayInfo" style="width: 300px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The aspx page "GetRecordInfo.aspx" is a simple ASP.NET page that accepts a post parameter ("recordID") and then displays a table with information matching the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
<html>
  <!-- inlude the jquery lib here..-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('.record').mouseover(function(e){
          var selectedRecordID = $(this).data('id');
          $("#divDisplayInfo").load("GetRecordInfo.aspx",
                                 { recordID: selectedRecordID },
                                 function(){
                                     $(this).css({left:e.pageX+'px', top:e.pageY+'px'});
                                 });
       });
   });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">#divDisplayInfo{position:absolute;}</style>
  <body>
   <a href="#" class="record" data-id="1">Record 1</a>
   <a href="#" class="record" data-id="2">Record 2</a>
   <a href="#" class="record" data-id="3">Record 3</a>

   <div id="divDisplayInfo" style="width: 300px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

First thing is to set the div to be `position:absolute` so you can re-position it at will.

Then when the ajax call completes use the events' pageX and pageY (the mouse coordinates) to relocate the div.

I have also altered you markup and script a bit to detach the hardcoded scripts on the `a` tags.

Demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/MwKJR/

Comment: Thanks, that looks really nice. One question .. in looking at how you "detached" the hardcoded scripts (which I like by the way) how do you still pass the value of the "data-id" to the jQuery functions?

Comment: You rock! Your demo was just what I needed. I adopted your code and got it working. Thanks so much for your help!