# Mouseover ajaxload script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hover, mouseover

Im attempting to create a mouseover event for pictures on a page to load a summary of that picture into a div container called "contentarea".  I'm new into coding, so please forgive my inaptitude. The code is below, but im not sure its going to work. Basically, I have 5 pictures of dogs on a webpage, and I want the mouseover event over a picture of the dog to load information from a seperate page called "content.html."  The content that is loaded should load from a  that has the same ID as the ID of the picture that is cursor is currently hovering over. The content will then load into a div that is below all the pictures called "contentarea." All pictures belong to the class dog.  I had tried to adapt someone else's code, but to no effect.

```
   <script>
   function(){
    $(.dog).mouseover(function(e) {
        var dogId = $(this).data('id');
        $("contentarea").load("content.html
         # " + dogId + " ");

    }); 
   </script>
```

Comment: you need to add quotes to your selector so change `$(.dog)` to `$('.dog')`

Comment: Are you using a server-side language, such as PHP?  You won't be able to load content dynamically using just HTML.

Comment: 'a div container called "contentarea"' what do you mean by 'called'? ID? Class? And just wonder how are you going to get different content by loading the same html file? I doubt hash will do the trick.

Comment: I'm just incorporating jquery, so I guess no server-side language.

Comment: div content with the ID content area

Comment: I'm trying to make a function with this http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Well, then at least you should use `$("#contentarea")`.

Comment: I thought that was what this line '$("contentarea").load("content.html
         # " + dogId + " ");' was doing. I'm not sure how to incorporate the variable for the div tag after the .load"content.html

Comment: appreciate the feedback, I have to run away quick, but anymore help on this code is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually load another html file using ajax, that is not a problem like zongweil said on his comment, because the content you are loading is not dynamic.

You need to add to specify that .dog is a string by using '. Additionally, please explain what you are trying to achieve using the # dogId. Are there anchors on the html file that you are loading? I don't think you will achieve the expected effect by adding the anchor to the loaded html. If you want to load the info of just one dog, then create several content.html file each with the proper id like content1.html, content2.html, etc and use this:

```
<script>
    $('.dog').mouseover(function(e) {
        var dogId = $(this).data('id');
        $("#contentarea").load("content" + dogId + ".html");
    }); 
   </script>
```

or instead use a single HTML file with the proper ids:

```
<div id="dogcontent1">
TEXT TEXT TEXT
</div>
<div id="dogcontent2">
TEXT TEXT TEXT
</div>
```

and then on the script use this:

```
<script>
    $('.dog').mouseover(function(e) {
        var dogId = $(this).data('id');
        $("#contentarea").load("content.html #dogcontent"+ dogId );
    }); 
   </script>
```

Comment: I was hoping that the dogid would be a variable is determined by whichever picture the mouse is on, thereby loading a DIV with the same name from the content.html file.  I was hoping to avoid creating multiple content files, and just having one large content file with seperate div containers, and this script would load the seperate div contianers based on the mouse over.

Comment: @Mickle Forentic: function is never called. Wrap it with another `$(...)` :). And check contentarea selector, you forgot '#'.

Comment: kind of like how this script works [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882227/loading-html-into-floating-div-with-jquery[link] . But instead of loading into a floating div, I have one div.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you are right on both things. Removed the function() and added the selector to contentarea.

Comment: @user1437779 that is no problem, if you name the <img src="..." id="5"> you will call content5.html. Now if you MUST use a single html file, I would make each dog content in the content.html file enclosed by a non-displaying div like this: <div id="dogcontent1" style="display:none"> and then add an extra line to the function after the load with $("#dogcontent"+dogId).show(). I think that solves your problem

Comment: @user1437779 I have edited my response with something that I think better matches what you intended.

Comment: Thank you Mickle. I have implemented the code on my site [here](http://dogsrfun.comze.com/subpages/LargeAmerican.html). However, its not modifying the div, seems like it is not recognizing the mouseover?

Comment: actually got everything to work now. I had to change the code a little bit. Here is below. Not sure if I had to include the img prefix for the dog class, and changed from data('id') to attr('id'). I was using an older version of jquery and this only seemed to work (before 1.4.7).

<script>
$('img.dog').click(function(e) {
    var id = ($(this).attr('id'));
    $("#contentarea").load("/content.html #dogcontent" + id);
}); 
Thank you again for the help, actually learned a little bit more about js.